# Ansible. Insert block of text FROM file to the file

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I know there is ansible.builtin.blockinfile exists. I can insert a block of text to the file with it, but the text should be provided as a 'block' in a task. Is it possible to use a file as a source for the 'block'?
I.e.:

```
- name: create/update somefile.config
  ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: /home/user/something/configuration.yaml
    insertbefore: "someline:"
    block: something/configuration.yaml
```

where `something/configuration.yaml` is a file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution

```
- name: create/update somefile.config
  ansible.builtin.blockinfile:
    path: /home/user/something/configuration.yaml
    insertbefore: "someline:"
    block: "{{ item }}"
  with_items:
    - "{{lookup('ansible.builtin.file', 'something/configuration.yaml') }}"
```